# dconf fails when running X application from alternate user

Tags: x11, security, users, dconf

In an effort to protect my personal files in my home directory, I am trying to run certain applications as an alternate user, but under the same graphical environment.

I have enabled X permissions by running the command: `xhost +si:localuser:$ALTUSER`

However, when I run a program like iceweasel (firefox) as the alternate user, there are a bunch of error messages in the console like this one:

`(iceweasel:10304): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.`

And a popup appears when the application starts which says:

`An error occurred while loading or saving configuration information for iceweasel. Some of your configuration settings may not work properly.`

In the first error message dconf is trying to create a folder called `/run/user/1000/dconf` but that's my main user (1000), not the id of the alternate user that is running the program (1001).

Is there a way to make dconf work correctly in this scenario?

Answer (score 6):

I needed to add a dash when switching users in the console. So `su - $ALTUSER` instead of `su $ALTUSER`. The dash `-` is an alias for the `-login` option of `su`.